# field 'EthashCachesOnDisk' is not defined in eth.Config

Tags: go-ethereum, docker

Trying to use my eth_config.toml file in ethereum docker container, but it throws this error for some config flags, one of them:

```
Fatal: /root/ethereum/data/eth_config.toml, line 10: field 'EthashCachesOnDisk' is not defined in eth.Config, see https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth#Config for available fields
```

it is not allowing me to use these flags too:

```
EthashCacheDir = "ethash"
EthashCachesInMem = 2
EthashDatasetDir = "/root/.ethash"
EthashDatasetsInMem = 1
EthashDatasetsOnDisk = 2
DiscoveryV5Addr = ":30304"
```

Is there some changes with new release?

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem by generating new `eth_config.toml` file using `geth dumpconfig`, so the structure is like this now:

```
[Eth]
NetworkId = 1
SyncMode = "fast"
LightPeers = 100
DatabaseCache = 768
GasPrice = 18000000000
EnablePreimageRecording = false

[Eth.Ethash]
CacheDir = "ethash"
CachesInMem = 2
CachesOnDisk = 3
DatasetDir = "/root/.ethash"
DatasetsInMem = 1
DatasetsOnDisk = 2
PowMode = 0
...
```